# https @font-face not working on IE 7 and IE8

Tags: css, fonts

We have a site that have a css below. The smiley face is there so that it would work with IE 7 and IE 8. However, the site fonts work fine on IE 9 , chrome, firefox etc but not on IE 7 and 8.

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'BrauerNeue-Bold';
        src: url('fonts/brauerneue-bold-webfont.eot');
        src: local('☺'), 
              url('fonts/brauerneue-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
              url('fonts/brauerneue-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
              url('fonts/brauerneue-bold-webfont.svg#webfontvlyLbaAW') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

I also verified the following:

1. The eot, woff and ttf fonts are located under Fonts folder.
2. Can download these files when accessed directly via URL.
3. First time the fonts gets loaded fine on IE7 and 8, but when we do CTRL + F5 or browser refresh the the above fonts doesnot get rendered.
4. Verified that the eot exists on IIS 7.0 mime type.
5. Does it matter if HTTP or HTTPS
6. Any IIS configuration required?

Could someone please help me how do I get the above fonts work on IE7 and 8

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this -

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    }
```

[**Read more here**](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax)

Comment: Thanks @Dipaks, any IIS MIME type configuration required?

Comment: @Myagdi There is one simple possiblity - When this syntax is used on an IIS server, IE9 users may not see the font. This can be solved in two ways. 1) Add the WOFF format to the list of MIME types. or 2) change the format('eot') portion to format('embedded-opentype'). Either one will solve issues with IE9.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing twice the `src` property. The second one erases the first.

And the support of font-face in IE7 and IE8 doesn't include

- [WOFF fonts](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff)
- [truetype fonts](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf)
- [svg fonts](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-fonts)

which means you must use a [embedded-opentype](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eot) font.

But as you erase the only possible value, you can't use it...

You may do this :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BrauerNeue-Bold';
    src: local('☺'), 
          url('fonts/brauerneue-bold-webfont.eot'),
          url('fonts/brauerneue-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
          url('fonts/brauerneue-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
          url('fonts/brauerneue-bold-webfont.svg#webfontvlyLbaAW') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Does it matter whether http or https?

Comment: @Myagdi I'm not sure of what you mean by this question. If all your files are accessible with the same protocol there is no problem.